# How to cover all elements within a div using parallax

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a website I'm making, and I want one section to cover the next using parallax. I've got a nice background image parallax, but I want the elements in the section being covered (the text, buttons, images, etc) to stay in place and also be covered.

I've messed with jQuery and such on this, but it's not working quite right. Upon `#ContentContainer2` reaching the top of the screen, it should have `ParallaxContainer` added as a class to it. I don't seem to be doing that, and I'm not seeing any errors.

```js
var distance = $('#ContentContainer2').offset().top;

$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() >= distance) {
    $('#ContentContainer2').addClass("ParallaxContainer");
  }
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  font-family: Open Sans;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 28px;
}

h1 {
  letter-spacing: -15px;
  font-family: Open Sans;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 200px;
  font-weight: 800;
  line-height: 200px;
}

.MainContainer {
  perspective: 1px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#ContentContainer {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 1;
  background: url(https://www.toptal.com/designers/subtlepatterns/patterns/sakura.png);
  background-color: rgb(250, 228, 216);
}

#ContentContainer2 {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 1;
}

#ContentContainer3 {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 1;
}

.Content {
  max-width: 750px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 75px 0;
}

p {
  margin: 75px 0;
}

.ParallaxContainer {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
  height: 100vh;
  transform: translateZ(-100px) scale(101);
}

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,800');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="MainContainer">
  <div class="ParallaxContainer" id="ContentContainer">
    <h1>
      Aloha!
    </h1>
  </div>

  <div id="ContentContainer2">
    <div class="Content">
      <p>ʻO Lorem Ipsum kahi haʻahaʻa wale nō o ka paʻi a me keʻano o nāʻoihana. ʻO Lorem Ipsum ka 'ōlelo papahana maʻamau o kaʻoihana o ka makahiki 1500, i ka wā i lawe ai kekahi mea paʻi kiʻiʻole i keʻano o ka type a scrambled iā ia e hana i kahi puke kiko'ī. ʻAʻole i ola wale i kaʻelima mau kenekulia, akā,ʻo ka leleʻana hoʻi i nāʻano o ka lolouila, e hoʻololiʻoleʻia ana. Ua hoʻolahaʻia i nā makahiki 1960 me ka hoʻokuʻuʻana i nā pepa Letraset i loko o nā moʻolelo Lorem Ipsum, a me nā mea hou aku me ka polokalamu hoʻopuka pākī e like me Aldus PageMaker me nā papa o Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="ContentContainer3">
    <div class="Content">
      <p>ʻO Lorem Ipsum kahi haʻahaʻa wale nō o ka paʻi a me keʻano o nāʻoihana. ʻO Lorem Ipsum ka 'ōlelo papahana maʻamau o kaʻoihana o ka makahiki 1500, i ka wā i lawe ai kekahi mea paʻi kiʻiʻole i keʻano o ka type a scrambled iā ia e hana i kahi puke kiko'ī. ʻAʻole i ola wale i kaʻelima mau kenekulia, akā,ʻo ka leleʻana hoʻi i nāʻano o ka lolouila, e hoʻololiʻoleʻia ana. Ua hoʻolahaʻia i nā makahiki 1960 me ka hoʻokuʻuʻana i nā pepa Letraset i loko o nā moʻolelo Lorem Ipsum, a me nā mea hou aku me ka polokalamu hoʻopuka pākī e like me Aldus PageMaker me nā papa o Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

([*codepen*](https://codepen.io/Gosintary/pen/qLPwME))

Can someone explain to me why this isn't working?

Comment: You can check http://johnpolacek.github.io/scrollorama/ but anyway nobody will help you without any code.

Comment: There's many ways to do parallax. What you've been doing up until now is probably just adjusting properties for a background image. Instead, as you point out, you want to have parallax act on the entire section. This can be done with CSS-only; here's an excellent CSS-only tutorial and the demo seems to be what you need: [https://www.okgrow.com/posts/css-only-parallax](https://www.okgrow.com/posts/css-only-parallax). If you need more control & features, that's when you look into using JS libraries.

Comment: @MarsAndBack, using the demo you linked I came up with exactly what I was looking for. Now I'm trying to figure out how I would use this on multiple sections?

https://codepen.io/Gosintary/pen/qLPwME

Would I need to use js to change the class of the second section so It would be then covered by the third?

Comment: Before diving into that demo code further, look for other parallax demo's that may already have the solution. Later on, if you still have technical trouble, that's when you make another unique, specific SO post.

Comment: Updated question

Comment: Your code on codepen produces a different output than that included in your question. Which is the latest version?

Comment: @MTCoster, it’s producing a different output? How so? The code is copy pasted.

Comment: The stack snippet has an extra scrolling stage at the beginning where the text goes past on the top with a white background.

Comment: @MTCoster, still don’t see what you mean, they both look the exact same.